# How can I use LOOCV in R with KNN?

Tags: r, cross-validation, knn

I am trying to use KNN with cancer data. At first, I only used separation data into train and test set, but I got unexpected results. So I want to use LOOCV to make sure.

I found only LOOCV with generalized linear models.

such as `glm.fit = glm(mpg ~ horsepower, data=Auto)`

So how can I use LOOCV in R with KNN?

**EDIT**

My code

```
wdbc<- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data",sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

wdbc<-wdbc[-1]

normalize <- function(x) {return ((x-min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}

wdbc_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(wdbc[2:31], normalize))
wdbc_train<-wdbc_n[1:469,]
wdbc_test<-wdbc_n[470:569,]
```

I uploaded the data and I excluded the first column which is the class label. Then I separated the data into train and test set. However, I want to use LOOCV in the separation instead of my separation above.

Comment: What code did you run? Can you provide the data set so that the error can be reproduced? Can you clarify why the result is wrong?

Comment: @jeza what exactly do you mean by `separation`?? when you say `I want to use LOOCV in the seperation`. Also, i have added a better alternative using `caret` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `knn.cv` function from `class` package is based on the ***leave one out cross validation***. The below implementation of this function gives you a *LOOCV* prediction of the `full` data (i.e. no separation into train and test).

```
library(class)

knn.cv(train = wdbc_n, 
      cl = as.factor(wdbc[,1]), 
      k = 4, prob = FALSE,                        # test for different values of k
      use.all = TRUE)
```

*Refer to* [knn.cv: R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/class/versions/7.3-14/topics/knn.cv)

The general concept in ***knn*** is to find the *right **k** value* (i.e. number of nearest neighbor) to use for prediction. This is done using cross validation.

> ***One better way*** would be to use the **`caret` package** to preform *cv* *on a grid to get the optimal k value*. Something like:

```
library(caret)

train.control <- trainControl(method  = "LOOCV")

fit <- train(V1~ .,
             method     = "knn",
             tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:20),
             trControl  = train.control,
             metric     = "Accuracy",
             data       = cbind(V1 = as.factor(wdbc[,1]), wdbc_n))
```

***Output: fit***

```
        k-Nearest Neighbors 

569 samples
 30 predictor
  2 classes: 'B', 'M' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 568, 568, 568, 568, 568, 568, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k   Accuracy   Kappa    
   1  0.9525483  0.8987965
   2  0.9595782  0.9132927
   3  0.9701230  0.9355404
   4  0.9683656  0.9318146
  ........................
  13  0.9736380  0.9429032
  14  0.9718805  0.9391558
  15  0.9753954  0.9467613
  16  0.9683656  0.9314173
  17  0.9736380  0.9429032
  18  0.9630931  0.9197531
  19  0.9648506  0.9236488
  20  0.9630931  0.9197531

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 15.

qplot(fit$results$k,fit$results$Accuracy,geom = "line",
      xlab = "k", ylab = "Accuracy")
```

[image: Accuracy Vs K]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Mankind_008. What I mean is that I want to use leave one out cross-validation. In other words, I do not want my separation `wdbc_train< wdbc_n[1:469,], wdbc_test<-wdbc_n[470:569,]` I would like to all data for training except one for test and then repeat that n times (i.e LOOCV).

Comment: Glad to help. You can use the same procedure for that. Just replacing training data ('wdbc_train`) with full data in above code. I will update the code with full data.

Comment: one set should be for testing my model

Comment: I know the idea of LOOCV but my problem is with codes, LOOCV = leave the first set and use other n-1 sets to train the model. After training in that round use that first set to test your model. In the next iteration leave the second set and use other n-1 sets to train. Repeat this method n times.

Comment: I got it. The thing is LOOCV is inbuilt into these functions I mentioned above. so whatever data set you provide  it will take care of it in LOOCV sense only to predict classes.  Do you want to control what becomes a part of test sets??

Comment: No I do not want to control test sets. I really appreciate your help if the codes could be updated as you got it. Thanks again

Comment: I just did. Check if this is what you need. You are welcome.

Comment: yes it is. Many thanks for your cooperation. you are really a very kind person.

Comment: As you know in knn we calculate the distances. For example in the built function knn, the Euclidean distance is used. Which distance is used in the codes you mentioned. because I want to use specified distances.

Comment: Both the above mentioned ways uses `knn` under the hood which uses Euclidean distance. If you want to try Manhattan distance or other norms you can try `kknn` method instead of `knn` with caret implementation.

Comment: ok suppose that I want to use fractional distances 0.5. Does that possible with above-mentioned codes with kknn instead of knn

Comment: kknn is for weighted knn but also performs unweighted knn. I am not that familiar wtih `kknn` package. You can try using `method = "kknn", tuneGrid   = expand.grid(kmax = 20, kernel = "rectangular", distance = 0.5)` in the caret code above. refer [kknn documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kknn/versions/1.3.1/topics/train.kknn) for details.

Comment: unfortunately, It does not work.

Comment: then I used `fit <-train.kknn(V2~.,data = wdbc_n,kmax = 20,kernel="rectangular",distance = 0.1)`, which is also does not work.