# Problem conducting K nearest neighbors using LOOCV

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

I have an example table that I would like to conduct KKNN to classify on. The variable, `V4` is the response and I want the classifier to see if a new data point will classify as `0` or `1` (the actual data has 12 columns and the 12th column is the response but I will simplify the example nonetheless

```
library(kknn)

data <- data.frame(
  V1=c(1.2, 2.5, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2), 
  V2=c(0.7, 1.8, 2.3, 3.9, 4.1), 
  V3=c(2.3, 3.7, 1.8, 4.2, 5.5), 
  V4= c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

Now, I want to build a  `kknn`classification via LOOCV using a `for` loop. Lets assume `kknn=3`

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  train_data <- data[-i, 1:3]
  train_data_response <- data.frame(data[-i, 4])
  colnames(train_data_response) <- "Response"
  test_set <- data[i, 3]
  model <- kknn(formula=train_data_response ~ ., data.frame(train_data), 
                data.frame(test_set), k=3, scale=TRUE) 
}
```

Now I get this error that says:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula, data = train) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'train_data_response'
```

Is there any way on how I can solve this error? I thought `kknn` accepts matrix or dataframes. My training and testing data are indeed dataframes so what gives?

Also, am I doing the LOOCV correctly?

Comment: Whether it is LOOCV or LCOOV, please clarify with its full form?

Comment: First of all, it's not clear what package `kknn` is coming from. Within your code you are creating `train_data_response` as a data frame (`train_data_response <-data.frame( data[-i,4])`) but then in the formula, you are calling it as the outcome variable `kknn(formula= train_data_response~., ...)`.

Comment: @Phil That's probably the main error. To the OP, why reinvent the wheel if LOOCV is what function [knn.cv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.cv.html) in package [class](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=class) does? See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118220/how-can-i-use-loocv-in-r-with-knn).

Comment: Its LOOCV. I am instructed to use a for loop

Comment: Also, the reason why I called train_data_response is because ``train_data_response`` has the outcome variables. I want the variables in ``train_data_response`` the be the response and variables 1-3 to be the predictor

Comment: Understood @myts999 but they way you were applying it in the code is that you were treating the data frame as a vector, which is why you were getting the error (formulas expect vectors as variables). If you had it as `kknn(formula=train_data_response[[1]] ~ ., ...)` it would presumably work (I'm saying this without testing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to leave one out from *train_data* to validate if our results are not driven by one specific row, and we won't touch *test_set*. Both are created even before doing the `kknn` without LOOCV,

```
> set.seed(42)
> smp <- sample.int(nrow(data), nrow(data)*.7)
> train_data <- data[smp, ]
> test_set <- data[-smp, ]
> fit <- kknn(formula=as.factor(Response) ~ ., train=train_data, 
+             test=test_set, k=3, scale=TRUE)
```

so we don't need the raw *data* anymore.

Say we want the result as a matrix `loo` of `nrow(loo) == (test_set)` and `ncol(loo) == (train_data)`, we initialize it doing

```
> loo <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow=nrow(test_set), ncol=nrow(train_data))
```

and fill it now leaving one out in the `kknn`.

```
> for (i in seq_len(nrow(train_data))) {
+   fit_loo <- kknn(formula=as.factor(Response) ~ ., train=train_data[-i, ], 
+                   test=test_set, k=3, scale=TRUE) 
+   loo[, i] <- as.character(fit_loo$fitted.values)
+ }
```

Note that we better classify the response `as.factor` in the formula, which adds safety if is numerish as in OP. The `fit$fitted.values` will, thus, also come back as a factor which in the matrix we want `as.character`, though, to prevent coercing the factors to integers.

Now we can do many things with the `loo` result, e.g. look which left out observation might influence model prediction,

```
> loo == fit$fitted.values
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

which is ninth row of *train_data* in this case.

Or calculate the ratio where `all` classifications were predicted correctly.

```
> mean(apply(loo == fit$fitted.values, 2, all))
[1] 0.9090909
```

---

*Data:*

Extended a little to have more observations.

```
data <- data.frame(
  V1=c(1.2, 2.5, 3.1, 4.8, 5.2), 
  V2=c(0.7, 1.8, 2.3, 3.9, 4.1), 
  V3=c(2.3, 3.7, 1.8, 4.2, 5.5), 
  Response= c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
data <- rbind.data.frame(data, data, data, row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: What is actually ``loo``? And why do we fit call the ``test_set`` in the formula? Usually ``test_set`` is called when you're ready to call the ``predict()`` function

Comment: @myts999 It's the result of LOOCV, where columns represent the classification results of the model when leaving out the respective row (i.e. column index represents left out row of *train_data*). Can't see *test_set* being called in `kknn`.

Comment: So is that just an optional step, I could just feed  ``train_data[-i, ]`` into the ``kknn`` function?

Comment: @myts999 Sure, you can leave out that extra line and specify directly in `kknn()`, see edit.

Comment: Also where did the ``model`` variable come from?

Comment: @myts999 Copy-paste issue, apologies. Certainly you have a `fit` w/o LOO with which we compare the LOO to validate, right? See edit, I used the terms `fit` and `fit_loo` for clarity.

Comment: Yes I have. Alright Thanks for the input!